# Xscreensaver turns on after leaving sleep mode

Tags: xscreensaver

When I wake my computer I always find out that xscreensaver is showing on the screen, despite it wasn't when I put computer into sleep.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the author of Xscreensaver himself, and he responded that this behavior is not possible to disable, since "it's basically impossible to tell "we were just asleep" apart from "the machine was just slow for some random-ass reason" ".